# SQL Syntax error when getting collection on listing

Tags: magento2, collection, sql

I've created my own module for managing leaflets in home page and i wanted to have a listing with existing leaflets. I've created UI_Component for listing (by Magicento) but when I go to listing page i have an error with SQL syntax.

```
[2021-05-14 07:50:23] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order ASC LIMIT 20' at line 1, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `example_widgets_leaflet` AS `main_table` ORDER BY order ASC LIMIT 20
```

From error I know it is something about `ORDER BY` statement. Sorting is made by adding this three lines of code in listing xml file (in column -> data -> config node):

```
<item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
<item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
```

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: What is you'r SQL and Magento version?

Comment: SQL - 5.7.29, Magento - 2.3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to "order" is a keyword in MySQL and you have used the same word for column name. You should change your table column name to something else. (I see you have used a column **order** to be ordered in below piece of code)

```
`main_table` ORDER BY order ASC LIMIT 20
```